# Java Instrumentation's API getObjectSize returning less bytes compared to GraphLayout.parseInstance from open JDK jol-core

Tags: java, apache-kafka, byte, apache-kafka-connect, sizeof

I am trying to find size of kafka `SinkRecord` in bytes because our Sink Connector buffers data for some time.

I have looked at various stackoverflow answers to find the right way to find approximate size in bytes.

[In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

But, I am seeing various results from different approaches.

```
final String JSON_WITHOUT_SCHEMA = "{\"userid\": \"User_1\"}";
JsonConverter converter = new JsonConverter();
HashMap<String, String> converterConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
converterConfig.put("schemas.enable", "false");
converter.configure(converterConfig, false);
SchemaAndValue noSchemaInputValue = converter.toConnectData("topic", JSON_WITHOUT_SCHEMA.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    SinkRecord noSchemaRecordValue =
            new SinkRecord(
                    "topic",
                    0,
                    Schema.STRING_SCHEMA,
                    "test",
                    noSchemaInputValue.schema(),
                    noSchemaInputValue.value(),
                    0);
System.out.println("Sink record size in bytes from instrumentation:" + InstrumentationAgent.getObjectSize(noSchemaRecordValue));


System.out.println("Sink record size in bytes from jol-core:" + GraphLayout.parseInstance(noSchemaRecordValue).totalSize());
```

```
Sink record size in bytes from instrumentation:56
Sink record size in bytes from jol-core:792
```

I also tried out [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_nashorn/blob/master/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/ir/debug/ObjectSizeCalculator.java) code and it returns 1168 bytes.

I have used [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-size-of-object) code for instrumentation API:

Question:

- Is the instrumentation API returning bytes after deep visit of object?
- Does kafka have any API to determine size of record in bytes?

Comment: I assume this is just an example? Ideally, you should use Connect `Struct` objects if you know the data ahead of time.